# How to get day, month, year, hours, minutes, seconds from a UNIX timestamp in Objective C on Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, date, timestamp

I have been going up and down through all kinds of reference docs and examples over the web but I just can't get how to get what day, month, year, hours, minutes will it be for a given timestamp in Objective C. Any ideas? The code I'm using for the purpose is like this:

```
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1286181000];
    unsigned int compFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:compFlags fromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"%d %d, %d:%d", [weekdayComponents day], [weekdayComponents month], [weekdayComponents hour], [weekdayComponents minute]);
    [date release];
    [weekdayComponents release];
```

Although the timestamp is for a day in October, the output gives me 19th of December.

Comment: btw: neither `date` nor `weekdayComponents` have to be released. This will probably lead to a crash.

Comment: i found this out just after i pasted this as it was indeed crashing and i was much too bothered with the wrong dates than the crashing. :D .thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs for [`dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:) say:

> This method is useful for creating
>   `NSDate` objects from `time_t` values
>   returned by BSD system functions.

Can you show the code that gave you that magic number `1286181000`? i.e. are you using a `time_t` value?

Comment: The number comes from a value stored in an integer column of a database and instead of that number really is a call to that function in the code which returns a NSNumber type and the value is something like the magic number I have pasted. Is there anyway I can typecast it into NSTimeInterval or something. I have been trying a lot this weekend but getting nowhere, things like: NSTimeInterval t = (long)[db getColumn:@"timestamp"]. So any ideas?

Comment: So I got it working, like: NSTimeInterval t = [[db getColumn:@"timestamp"] doubleValue]; and then using the NSTimeInterval later on in crafting the NSDate. The db class object returned an NSNumber reference and hence the situation. Thanks.

Comment: @kumar glad you got it working. If you found this answer helpful, feel free to mark it as "answered" and give it an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

```
//  for age validation  (dynamic age in date picker for 18-100 year)

 NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *dc_min = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dc_min setYear:-100];
    NSCalendar *cal_min = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    NSDate *pastDate_min = [cal_min dateByAddingComponents:dc_min toDate:today  options:0];
    [datePicker setMinimumDate:pastDate_min];


    NSDateComponents *dc_max = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dc_max setYear:-18];
    NSCalendar *cal_max = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    NSDate *pastDate_max = [cal_max dateByAddingComponents:dc_max toDate:today  options:0];

    [datePicker setMinimumDate:pastDate_min];
    [datePicker setMaximumDate:pastDate_max];


    [datePicker setDate:[datePicker maximumDate]];
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```